# How to hide a series of rows in Excel until the value changes

Tags: vba, excel

So first of all i have a macro in my excel workbook that Hides rows based on a cell value. And this works. First of all here's what my worksheet looks like:

#### Screenshot of my worksheet

[image: Screenshot of my worksheet]

And here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Hide()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    With wks
     wks.Select
      Rows.Hidden = False
      Lastrow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row          '
               Set Rng = Range("H1:H" & Lastrow) '
               For Each cell In Rng
                    If cell.Value = "Closed" Then  '
                       cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next cell
    End With
    Exit For
Next wks

MsgBox "All Rows containing Closed in Column H have been hidden", vbInformation, "Information"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So this will hide any row that contains "Closed" on my first worksheet in the column "H".

But as you can see on  my print screen, i would like to hide all the rows between the first met value "closed" and the second value "closed". And do this until the last row. But i don't know how to do this, can someone help me please?

Comment: You could change the cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True to something like
.Range(cell, cell.end(xldown).offset(-1,0)).EntireRow.Hidden = True.

Comment: @Alex4336 Sorry i don't understand your code. How this code woud get to stop hiding rows? In my screenshot there the second "closed" so it should stop there, in my screenshot it's closed but it can be anything else, like open.

Comment: My code starts from the cell in your loop, and expands the selection downwards to the cell above the next cell with a value in it, so in your example it should hide the rows from the orange Closed to the row just above the blue closed. This is assuming you have blank rows between every occurence of closed in the cell.

Comment: @Alex4336 It kinda works for the first two "closed" met but then it stops working. It also doesn't hide the row where the "closed" is so i added the cell.EntireRow.hidden = true. But then it say it can't run it in break mode

Comment: If it can't run in break mode it's because some code is already running or in debug mode. Reset the code, and you should be able to do it again. As for the the hidding of rows part, I haven't tested my suggestion, so I have no idea if it works.

Comment: @Alex4336 See screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/4glvgkkyt/

Comment: cell.value = "Closed" and cell.value = "closed" are not the same.
I'd suggest using Ucase(cell.value)= "CLOSED". That works for me at least, except if the last entry in the H column is closed it will hide every row beneath it.

Comment: How many pairs of 'Closed' do you expect? Is it guaranteed that 'Closed' will always come in pairs? What do you do with the orphaned 'Closed' if an od one exists?

Comment: @Alex4336 It doesn't work. I changed to UCase but still it doesn't change much. Sometimes there's even an "open" And it hides it too with that modification. It doesn't hide the "open" one with the not modified code tho

Comment: @Jeeped Hi Jeeped. Close doesn't comes in pairs. It mays be Closed, then another one Open, and there again a CLosed one, it's random. I would like to hide rows for every blank cell after the "Closed" only and do this until there another value in the cell. It could be anything as a value, Open or Closed. And if it's closed to the same as before, if open don't do anything and go further until the next Closed.

Comment: You lost me there. Do you want the row containing the word closed to remain visible, or should it be closed aswell?
Did you use my earlier suggestion or did you add the cell.entireRow.hidden aswell ?

Comment: @Alex4336 I used your solution only and it left the row containing "closed" visible. It also hides some other rows that contain "open". And it doesn't always hide the rows following the "closed" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in a fast way, try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Hide()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim Lastrow As String
  Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
  Dim cell As Variant
  For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Rows.Hidden = False
    Lastrow = wks.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Lastrow > 1 Then
      cell = wks.Range("H1:H" & Lastrow).Value
      i = 1: Set Rng = Nothing
      While i <= Lastrow
        For i = i To Lastrow
          If LCase(cell(i, 1)) = "closed" Then Exit For
        Next
        For i = i To Lastrow
          If LCase(cell(i, 1)) = "closed" Or cell(i, 1) = "" Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
              Set Rng = wks.Rows(i)
            Else
              Set Rng = Union(Rng, wks.Rows(i))
            End If
          Else
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      Wend
      If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox "All Rows containing Closed in Column H have been hidden", vbInformation, "Information"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To do it without while and have easier access for conditions:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Hide()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim Lastrow As String
  Dim i As Long, hideB As Boolean
  Dim cell As Variant
  For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Rows.Hidden = False
    Lastrow = wks.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Lastrow > 1 Then
      cell = wks.Range("H1:H" & Lastrow).Value
      Set Rng = Nothing: hideB = False
      For i = 1 To Lastrow
        If Len(cell(i, 1)) Then
          'this determinates if the line will be hidden
          hideB = (LCase(cell(i, 1)) = "closed")
          'if you want to check G also => hideB = (LCase(cell(i, 1)) = "closed") And (LCase(wks.cells(i, "G")) = "keyword2")
        End If
        If hideB Then
          If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = wks.Rows(i)
          Else
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, wks.Rows(i))
          End If
        End If
      Next
      If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox "All Rows containing Closed in Column H have been hidden", vbInformation, "Information"
End Sub
```

Comment: It says. "Unable to set the hidden property of the range Class" when i try to run it

Comment: Yes. there are conditionall formatting on some rows

Comment: When i click the debug button it highlights: "If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Hidden = True"

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I have one more question. I would like to check the value of the cell next to the blank cell before hiding it. Is it possible? Like it's currently checking H column on row 3 and i would like to check the G column on row 3 before hiding.

Comment: while it would slow down the process itself, you can do it with `wks.Cells(i, 7).value`... but this double-loop-inside-loop is not suited for that... I'll create a different way to do the same, and add it to my answer... but may take some time...

Comment: No don't over do thank you already. I have found another solution. It was deleting lines i didn't want to deleter so i just add a blank space and it works so.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub Hide()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With wks

            .Rows.Hidden = False
            lastrow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastrow

                If .Cells(i, "H").Value = "Closed" Then

                    startrow = i + 1
                    Do Until .Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = "Closed" Or i + 1 > lastrow

                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                    If .Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = "Closed" Then

                        If i >= startrow Then .Rows(startrow).Resize(i - startrow + 1).Hidden = True
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Next wks

    MsgBox "All Rows containing Closed in Column H have been hidden", vbInformation, "Information"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It hides some cells with open too. It also doesn't hide the cell it self. And it doesn't work with every row. Could it be something wrong with my excel file?

Comment: You said between the rows, not including, so I coded it that way. As for your data, I cannot say without seeing it for real, I created data based upon the image and it worked, but maybe you have something else not catered for.